# React component is not getting updated when state changes into the redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

REDUX

```
return{...state,importGridData:importGridData)
```

Here the importGridData assign to state varialbes inside the redux initial state

Component Render

```
const {importGridData} = this.props
this.setState({importGrdData,importGridData)
```

I am getting the data here into the react component using the props
And I want assign this data into my datagrid component

```
<DataGrid data={this.state.importGrdData}
```

I can not give the setState inside the render method so how can I update my datagrid data?

Is there any thing missing here ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to update the component state from redux state.

In that case, as mentioned by Bhojendra, you can use `componentDidUpdate` method as below.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  const { importGridData } = this.props;

  if(prevProps.importGridData !== importGridData) {
    // update the state
    this.setState({ importGrdData: importGridData })
  }
}
```

But, instead of copying the redux state to local state then binding the data to DataGrid, I would recommend directly using the `redux` state to bind the grid in the `render` method if you don't have any other dependency.

```
render() {
   const { importGridData } = this.props;
   return <DataGrid data={importGridData} />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be colon `:` not comma `,`:

```
this.setState({importGrdData:importGridData})
```

Ah, I see spelling difference (Grd and Grid):

<strike>Also, you may just write: (because you have same name)</strike>

```
this.setState({importGrdData})
```

---

You can update the state in componentDidUpdate hook so that after you get the props it will update the state:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if(this.state.importGrdData !== prevState.importGrdData) {
    // update the state
  }
}
```

To know more about componentDidUpdate, look at the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate).

Only in rare case, you may use [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops).

Answer (score 0):

I am using "componentWillReceiveProps" lifecycle for recieve next props.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){  
    this.setState({   
        importGrdData:    nextProps,  
    });
}
```

The code is an example.I hope it can be helpful for you.Thanks

Comment: use `getDerivedStateFromProps` instead if `componentWillReceiveProps`.